# Can't view PDF (with embedded swf) on Android devices

Tags: android, actionscript-3, pdf, flash

I have a pdf with embedded swf inside it, i was able to view this PDF on desktop using browsers after installing Adobe Reader XI and flash player plugin.

My problem is that i am trying to view this pdf on Android but i can't, as you might know flash player on the Android is no longer supported, i tried to download the PDF on the Android device and open it with Acrobat Reader (for Android) but it didn't work.

this is a link for a sample PDF with swf embedded in side it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8y0q0d9d9r66vie/1-Subject%20A4%20Notebook%201%20p.%204.pdf

If you know a converting tool to convert the PDF(with embedded swf) to any format that Android can understand i think it will help.

Comment: If i can convert the PDF to SWF then i might use Adobe Air to view it.
I tried the "swftools-0.9.0" but it export only the pages and leave the audio.

Comment: according to Acrobat Reader forum this PDF can't be opened inside Android see this link:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/5228598#5228598,

but is there a work around for this or it is a dead end :(.

Comment: I would say it will likely end in a dead end. I would suggest avoiding Flash on Android, as it is no longer supported. IMO, embedding Flash in a PDF is quit odd to begin with.

Comment: Thanks Tanis you are right, but the problem is that we have a third party solution that produces this PDF, and we try to make it viewable from Android.

Comment: Ruboto + Origami port to android + decompilation + Decompiled Resources to View + engine to play swf... That is too much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He can offer 1million reps if he wants, the fact is he's chosen the wrong technology stack for andriod.  With a lot of effort, you might get the Flash player to run on an android browser on a very limited set of devices, (and none with android 4.0+), but that still won't run it inside a pdf viewer.

Comment: Ok, i give up, it is look like there is no way, marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential workaround if you are absolutely unable to find any solutions -

1. Convert the PDF to HTML5 (perhaps with [this resource](http://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-html5-converter/))
2. Convert the swf to HTML5 (perhaps with [Google Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/))
3. Embed the HTML5 code from the swf into that of the PDF

Depending on the complexity of your functionality, the translation should be quite seamless. The functionality usually dropped by a Swiffy conversion is more sophisticated things like input/output etc.

All in all, it can indeed be quite difficult to support Flash on mobile devices, especially when it is embedded in an unordinary way. Hopefully this helps to make things seem less at a standstill.

Comment: Thanks XLXMXNT, i tried the converter (#1) it converts the pdf page to png image, so we lost the audio and the animation.
about #2 & #3 i don't have the swf it is embedded in the PDF.

The problem is that the PDF generated by a third party tool we just want to make it readable from Android.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was answered some time this year. It should be noted however that it is not guaranteed to work especially in new devices since am sure you know the issue concerning flash on android.

This isn't a straigh forward way of solving it but you can download the swfdec source code (http://swfdec.freedesktop.org), cross-compile the swfdec source code to android then port the  swfdec surface to android's View class